# How do I deal with commas/tabs that are part of the data in CSV/TSV in MarkLogic

Tags: csv, marklogic, nosql

I am trying to load a CSV file that have commas as part of the data into MarkLogic using RecordLoader. The data loads but MarkLogic takes commas that are part of the data as delimiters. I tried to escape commas by using backslashes but didn't work and the data remains dirty with the backslashes. I thought about replacing the data commas with other symbols so that I can change them back to commas after I load but I don't know if there is a way to modify the data after I load and I would have to reposition the XML tags line by line.

How can I load a CSV/TSV file and keep the commas/tabs that are part of the data as part of the data and not as delimiters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RecordLoader's DelimitedDataLoader doesn't support any escaping today. If you want to add it as a patch, https://github.com/marklogic/recordloader/blob/master/src/java/com/marklogic/recordloader/xcc/DelimitedDataLoader.java#L102 is the place to start looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Although you asked about RecordLoader, you could also use the [MarkLogic Content Pump](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp). See [Creating Documents from Delimited Text Files](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_70366).